# How to create qualifier annotation in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

*I create a qualifier in Java as follows*

**ApplicationContext.java**

```
@Qualifier
public @interface ApplicationContext {}
```

**Question:** *How to create the same in Kotlin*

Answer (score 3):

Just like this:

```
@Qualifier
annotation class ApplicationContext
```

Comment: Is this correct ? ... Have you used it ? ...because I am not trying to create a annotation ....  I also came across ( `https://medium.com/@elye.project/dagger-2-for-dummies-qualifier-5c7e78a4d3a6` ) where they say `@Named` is alternative in Kotlin similar to `@ Qualifier` in java

Comment: It is one-to-one mirror of the aforementioned Java's code (just check the bytecode), which is a plain annotation (taking this fact you are actually trying to create an annotation). `@Named` is javax.inject Annotation which is available for Java as much as for Kotlin and is basically a string-backed qualifier itself (check the source - it is annotated with `@Qualifier`; documentation will do too). Speaking of Dagger2 - `@Qualifier`-annotated annotations and `@Named` a basically two ways to do the same thing - whichever suits your style best